# How to change border color to primary when the OutlinedTextField is valid

Tags: android, kotlin, validation, android-jetpack-compose

I have three questions.

1. I am using password validation in jetpack compose. I want to change the outline color of `OutlinedTextField` to primary is the password is valid, otherwise `Color.Red`. I have a Validator file which checks if the password is valid, and I want this to be reflected on the SignupScreen.kt.
2. How to merge ValidatePassword.kt and Validator.kt files, One is an Class another an Object.
3. How can the condition Row be validated?

I accept any workflow on how to validate or a practical answer.

SignUpScreen.kt

```
    @Composable
fun SignUpScreen(signupViewModel: SignupViewModel = viewModel()) {

    val passwordError by signupViewModel.passwordError.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState()}
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Scaffold(
        modifier= Modifier,
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
        },
        content= { it
        //Screen content
     Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(28.dp)
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state=scrollState),verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {

                        NormalTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.hello))
                        HeadingTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.create_account))
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.first_name),
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.FirstNameChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.firstNameError
                        )

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.last_name),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.LastNameChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.lastNameError
                        )

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.email),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.message),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.EmailChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.emailError
                        )

                        PasswordTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.password),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_lock),
                            onTextSelected = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.PasswordChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.passwordError,
                            )

                        if (signupViewModel.isNotMatching) {
                            Text(text = "Passwords do not match!", color = Color.Red)
                        }

                        //insert condition row
                        Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)) {
                            ConditionRow(condition = "Minimum 8 characters", check = passwordError.hasMinimum)
                            ConditionRow(condition = "Has special character", check = passwordError.hasSpecialCharacter)
                            ConditionRow(condition = "Has capitalized letter", check = passwordError.hasCapitalizedLetter)
                        }

                        CheckboxComponent(onTextSelected = {
                            BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.TermsAndConditionsScreen)
                        }
                        ) {
                            signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.PrivacyPolicyCheckBoxClicked(it))
                        }

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))

                        ButtonComponent(
                            value = stringResource(id = R.string.register),
                            onButtonClicked = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.RegisterButtonClicked)
                                BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.GeoMarkerScreen)
                                if (signupViewModel.userExists.value){
                                scope.launch { snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("The email address is already in use by another account!") }
                            }},
                            isEnabled = signupViewModel.allValidationsPassed.value
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

                        DividerTextComponent()

                        LoginClickableTextComponent(tryingToLogin = true,onTextSelected = {
                            BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.LoginScreen)
                        })
                    }

                }

                if(signupViewModel.signUpInProgress.value) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                }

            }
    })
}

@Composable
fun ConditionRow(
    condition: String,
    check: Boolean
) {
    val color by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = if (check) Color.Green else Color.Red,
        label = "text color"
    )

    val icon = if (check) {
        Icons.Rounded.Check
    } else {
        Icons.Rounded.Close
    }

    Row {
        Icon(
            imageVector = icon,
            tint = color,
            contentDescription = "status icon"
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = condition,
            color = color
        )
    }
}
```

SignupViewModel.kt

```
class SignupViewModel (private val validatePassword: ValidatePassword = ValidatePassword()): ViewModel() {

    private val TAG = SignupViewModel::class.simpleName

    var registrationUIState = mutableStateOf(RegistrationUIState())

    var allValidationsPassed = mutableStateOf(false)

    var signUpInProgress = mutableStateOf(false)

    var userExists = mutableStateOf(false)

    var password by mutableStateOf("")
        private set
    // match password and confirm password
    var confirmPassword by mutableStateOf("")
        private set

    val isNotMatching by derivedStateOf {
            password != confirmPassword
        }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val passwordError =
        snapshotFlow { password }
            .mapLatest { validatePassword.execute(it) }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
                initialValue = PasswordValidationState()
            )

    fun onEvent(event: SignupUIEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is SignupUIEvent.FirstNameChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    firstName = event.firstName
                )
                printState()
            }

            is SignupUIEvent.LastNameChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    lastName = event.lastName
                )
                printState()
            }

            is SignupUIEvent.EmailChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    email = event.email
                )
                printState()

            }


            is SignupUIEvent.PasswordChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    password = event.password
                )
                printState()

            }

            is SignupUIEvent.ConfirmPasswordChanged -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    confirmPassword = event.confirmPassword
                )
                printState()
            }

            is SignupUIEvent.RegisterButtonClicked -> {
                signUp()
            }

            is SignupUIEvent.PrivacyPolicyCheckBoxClicked -> {
                registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
                    privacyPolicyAccepted = event.status
                )
            }
        }
        validateDataWithRules()
    }


    private fun signUp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside_signUp")
        printState()
        createUserInFirebase(
            email = registrationUIState.value.email,
            password = registrationUIState.value.password
        )
    }

    private fun validateDataWithRules() {
        val fNameResult = Validator.validateFirstName(
            fName = registrationUIState.value.firstName
        )

        val lNameResult = Validator.validateLastName(
            lName = registrationUIState.value.lastName
        )

        val emailResult = Validator.validateEmail(
            email = registrationUIState.value.email
        )

        val passwordResult = Validator.validatePassword(
            password = registrationUIState.value.password
        )
        val confirmPasswordResult = Validator.validatePasswordMatch(
            password = registrationUIState.value.password,
            confirmPassword = registrationUIState.value.confirmPassword,
        )

        val privacyPolicyResult = Validator.validatePrivacyPolicyAcceptance(
            statusValue = registrationUIState.value.privacyPolicyAccepted
        )


        Log.d(TAG, "Inside_validateDataWithRules")
        Log.d(TAG, "fNameResult= $fNameResult")
        Log.d(TAG, "lNameResult= $lNameResult")
        Log.d(TAG, "emailResult= $emailResult")
        Log.d(TAG, "passwordResult= $passwordResult")
        Log.d(TAG,"confirmPasswordResult=$confirmPasswordResult")
        Log.d(TAG, "privacyPolicyResult= $privacyPolicyResult")

        registrationUIState.value = registrationUIState.value.copy(
            firstNameError = fNameResult.status,
            lastNameError = lNameResult.status,
            emailError = emailResult.status,
            //passwordError = passwordResult.status,
            confirmPasswordError = confirmPasswordResult.status,
            privacyPolicyError = privacyPolicyResult.status
        )


        allValidationsPassed.value = fNameResult.status && lNameResult.status &&
                //passwordResult.status
                emailResult.status && confirmPasswordResult.status && privacyPolicyResult.status

    }


    private fun printState() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside_printState")
        Log.d(TAG, registrationUIState.value.toString())
    }


    private fun createUserInFirebase(email: String, password: String) {

        signUpInProgress.value = true


        FirebaseAuth
            .getInstance()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside_OnCompleteListener")
                Log.d(TAG, " isSuccessful = ${it.isSuccessful}")


                signUpInProgress.value = false
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.GeoMarkerScreen)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside_OnFailureListener")
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception= ${it.message}")
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception= ${it.localizedMessage}")
                userExists.value = true
                //Observe this signUpUIState in SignUpScreen and show SnackBar using Scaffold in SignUpScreen

            }
    }


}
```

Validator.kt

```
package com.example.bettehomes.data.rules

object Validator {
    fun validateFirstName(fName: String): ValidationResult {
        return ValidationResult(
            (!fName.isNullOrEmpty() && fName.length >= 2)
        )

    }

    fun validateLastName(lName: String): ValidationResult {
        return ValidationResult(
            (!lName.isNullOrEmpty() && lName.length >= 2)
        )
    }

    fun validateEmail(email: String): ValidationResult {
        return ValidationResult(
            (!email.isNullOrEmpty())
        )
    }

    fun validatePassword(password: String): ValidationResult {
        return ValidationResult(
            (!password.isNullOrEmpty() && password.length >= 4)
        )
    }

    fun validatePrivacyPolicyAcceptance(statusValue:Boolean):ValidationResult{
        return ValidationResult(
            statusValue
        )
    }
    fun validatePasswordMatch(password:String, confirmPassword:String): ValidationResult{
        return ValidationResult( password == confirmPassword)
    }
}

data class ValidationResult(
    val status: Boolean = false
)
```

I have also another file: ValidatePassword.kt, but even while I enter valid Password, it doesn't reflect on SignUpScreen.kt UI. I want to merge these two files into one.

ValidatePassword:

```
package com.example.bettehomes.data.rules

class ValidatePassword {

    fun execute(password: String): PasswordValidationState {
        val validateSpecialCharacter = validateSpecialCharacter(password)
        val validateCapitalizedLetter = validateCapitalizedLetter(password)
        val validateMinimum = validateMinimum(password)

        val hasError = listOf(
            validateMinimum,
            validateCapitalizedLetter,
            validateSpecialCharacter
        ).all { it }

        return PasswordValidationState(
            hasMinimum = validateMinimum,
            hasSpecialCharacter = validateSpecialCharacter,
            hasCapitalizedLetter = validateCapitalizedLetter,
            successful = hasError
        )
    }

    private fun validateSpecialCharacter(password: String): Boolean =
        password.contains(Regex("[!@#\$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>?]"))

    private fun validateCapitalizedLetter(password: String): Boolean =
        password.matches(Regex(".*[A-Z].*"))

    private fun validateMinimum(password: String): Boolean =
        password.matches(Regex(".{6,}"))
}
```